# How i create application B that would be able to communicate with running application A?

Tags: development, c++, application

I have background application **A**.

I want to create application **B** to configure application **A** on the fly.

So, how can I detect if **A** is running and send some messages to **A**?

Comment: You could [start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Main_IPC_methods), but I suppose in this generality this is not the right venue for your question.  (If you had problems with, say, IPC via specific UNIX-y ways...)

Comment: @sr_ consider to convert your comment to answer

Comment: This is probably more appropriate on StackOverflow.com

Comment: It might be appropriate here but it's hard to tell because it's worded so generally. There are many different situations where this could apply, and many different answers. Mireck, I think it would help if you better describe *A* and *B* and the environment in which they are running.

Comment: Do you have control over the code of prorgram *A*? If that's the case, I could do a small presentation of IPC. If not, I'm afraid there's no general answer. You'll have to give us the name of program *A* and we may look up ways to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change the program's configuration, the typical method of doing that is to update its conf file, then send it a SIGHUP signal, which it is programmed to respond to by reloading its conf file ( see `signal(7)` ).  As Coren said, you typically have the program store its pid in a file in /var/run when it starts so you can later send it the signal.

If you need more complex communication with the program, you will want to use either a fifo or unix domain socket.  A fifo ( see `fifo(7)` and `mkfifo(3)` ) is simpler, but the daemon can only communicate with a single control program.  Unix domain sockets ( see `unix(7)` ) are more complicated to use, but you can accept connections from multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

Background application are called "[daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)" in Unix & Linux world.

They are standardized in many ways, one way is how to get their pid. They usually create a pid file in `/var/run`.

With their pid, you can know nearly everything about them with the help of [/proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc). You can know if it's still active, memory used, memory mapping, files open, etc, etc.

And as sr_ said, you can then use IPC methods in order to communicate with it.